# How to display exact timing with Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[In this link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#view_network_timing), it shows how to use network timing pane/window. But, I realized that the timings are shown in relative: there is no "exact timing" here. For example I wanted to see the exact time of the starting of an ajax and it's end of course. This should be the string that I need to see in this pane as an "exact start time" of an ajax request

11.17.2017 10:00:00(GMT+1)

How can I achieve this in Chrome Developer Tools? Are there any place written the exact date of the network events?

Comment: You can star the [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=955892) if you want to see it in a future version of Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily what you asked for, but since you asked for any exact dates of network events, it's possible to capture the Response Date (time the response message was originated). If you right click on one of your columns, then choose Response Headers->Manage Header Columns->Add custom header->(type in Date). Unfortunately, it is not the actual start date of the request. I don't know if there's a way to capture that in devtools aside from modifying code to console.log your start date.

[image]

Comment: :( Yes I knew that we can get response date but don't know either if there is a way to get the date of request. Strange isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. Seems like a simple metric for google to capture too.

Comment: [**UPDATE 2023**] In the latest Chrome versions (Version 114.0.5735.198 as of writing this), there was no "Date" field listed under the "Response Headers". I had to add it manually by selecting "Manage Header Columns" > "Add custom header..." and then typing "Date". And after that it immediately appeared in the list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the console and monkey-patched XMLHttpRequest thusly:

```js
const original = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function( ) {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), arguments);
    return original.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Worked for me.

```
2022-11-17T19:20:26.013Z Arguments(3) ['POST', 'http://localhost:7450/realms/CLIENTID/protocol/openid-connect/token', true, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
2022-11-17T19:21:26.286Z Arguments(3) ['POST', 'http://localhost:7450/realms/CLIENTID/protocol/openid-connect/token', true, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

I assume it's also possible to monkey-patch `fetch` as well if that's what's doing it.